# Can i check many action params at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, action

I have actions with many params

```
test_action(a, b, c, d ,e ,f)
```

b, c, d ,e ,f may be nil and it's normal. In actions Im need check it on nil

```
do_somethig if (!b.nil? OR !c.nil? OR !d.nil? OR...)
```

count params may increase. Please ask me, can I check all params(without first) in one if without OR ?

Comment: It's `or`, not `OR` ... and in your case `||` ;-)

Comment: Yes, I write or in uppercase to highlight it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!b.nil?` is basically the same as just `b`. That means you can rewrite

```
do_something if (!b.nil? OR !c.nil? OR !d.nil? OR ...)
```

as

```
do_something if (b || c || d || ...)
```

Or you could write something like this when you think it is easier to read and understand:

```
do_something if [b, c, d, ...].any?
```